# Java NullPointerException When Storing Multiple Strings

Tags: java

I am writing a program and I desperately need some help.

I have a class that needs to keep track of multiple objects simultaneously.

I tried to do it like this:

```
public class tracker {
   private String[] Name;
   private int NameCounter;

   public void getName(String name) {
      Name[NameCounter] = name;
      NameCounter = NameCounter + 1;
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      getName("Name1");
      getName("Name2");

      System.out.println(Name[1] + " " + Name[2])
   }
}
```

I get an error that says that I have a NullPointerException. What do i do?

Comment: Hey as suggested by others in the answer you have to instantiate the `Name` variable, but this would need you to know the array size before-hand. If you do not know the size before-hand then you can try using a Collection like `ArrayList`.

Comment: naming convention...class name, first letter should be capitalized.

Answer (score 5):

`Name` is null because you don't instantiate the array.

You can do

```
private String[] Name = new String[2];
```

But as an array has a fixed length, I would recommend using an ArrayList here if you think you may need more names :

```
public class tracker {
   private ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(); // please follow naming conventions

   public void addName(String name) { // getName is a baaad name for a method that changes a variable
      names.add(name);
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) { // main, not mian
      addName("Name1");
      addName("Name2");
      System.out.println(names.get(0) + " " + names.get(1)) // the second one is at index 1, not 0
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Though it is irrelevant to your question, yet I am posting it.
By Java standards, the method getName rather be named as setName, so that name of the method can convey the right purpose.

Comment: To add, follow Java naming conventions. Variables name should start with lowercase letter. And it is relevant. :) +1 for it.

Comment: In fact I prefer to name it `addName` here (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

This should execute

```
public class tracker {
    private String[] Name = new String[2];
    private int NameCounter;

    public void getName(String name) {
        Name[NameCounter] = name;
        NameCounter = NameCounter + 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        tracker t = new tracker();
        t.getName("Name1");
        t.getName("Name2");

        System.out.println(t.Name[0] + " " + t.Name[1]);
    }
}
```